# Sorting Spans by a Calculation of Span Values in Child Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, sorting

I have code like this, which is generated with shortcodes on WordPress (populating the name, prices, etc)

```
<div class="productgrid">
<span class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 1</span>
    <a href="#/">
        <span class="prodprices">
            <span class="prodcost">90.00</span>
            +
            <span class="prodfee">10.00</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
    <span class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 2</span>
    <a href="#/">
        <span class="prodprices">
            <span class="prodcost">20.00</span>
            +
            <span class="prodfee">5.00</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
    <span class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 3</span>
    <a href="#/">
        <span class="prodprices">
            <span class="prodcost">30.00</span>
            +
            <span class="prodfee">10.00</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</span>
</div>
```

Which would appear as

```
Product 1 90.00 + 10.00 

Product 2 20.00 + 5.00 

Product 3 30.00 + 10.00
```

I can't add any attributes within the spans because of how WordPress deals with shortcodes.

I need to **Sort the products by smallest to largest total price, so the sum of both spans within each**

```
Product 2 20.00 + 5.00 

Product 3 30.00 + 10.00 

Product 1 90.00 + 10.00
```

And I know in this example it would just be `prodcost`, but the `prodfee` isn't always going to be as small so the **total cost** is what I need to sort by.

Comment: So you want to sort the items by `prodcost` + `prodfee`  in ascending order? Is this already displayed on the page when you want to sort it? Or you can sort it before printing it (with PHP maybe)?

Comment: show us the code you use to generate the html. As that is the one you need to sort, not the resulting html.

Comment: @Ovidash the code is above - the only thing changing is the names and values of product via short codes

Comment: @Ivan it’s already on the page - unfortunately the importer on WordPress that gets the information from a feed can only sort on the first node and can’t do calculations, and the feed itself can’t sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```js
document.getElementById( 'sort' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll( '.product' );

  for ( var i = 0, val = []; i < els.length; i++ ) {
    val[ i ] = { index: i, value: Number( document.querySelectorAll( '.prodcost' )[ i ].innerText ) + Number( document.querySelectorAll( '.prodfee' )[ i ].innerText ) };
  }

  val.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return a.value > b.value ? 1 : a.value == b.value ? 0 : -1
  } )

  for ( var i = 0, str = ''; i < val.length; i++ ) {
    str += '<div class="product">' + els[ val[ i ].index ].innerHTML + '</div>'
  }

  document.querySelector( '.productgrid' ).innerHTML = str
} )
```

```html
<input id="sort" type="button" value="Sort">

<div class="productgrid">
  <div class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 1</span>
    <a href="#/">
      <span class="prodprices">
        <span class="prodcost">90.00</span> + <span class="prodfee">10.00</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 2</span>
    <a href="#/">
      <span class="prodprices">
        <span class="prodcost">20.00</span> + <span class="prodfee">5.00</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <span class="prodname">Product 3</span>
    <a href="#/">
      <span class="prodprices">
        <span class="prodcost">30.00</span> + <span class="prodfee">10.00</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```